# Vuex: Use deferred promises in store

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vuex

I have multiple Vuex modules which should access a single value (feature flag bool) which comes from an API. I want this API value to be loaded lazily, meaning just when the first action inside of another store module needs it. I imagine something like this:

```
export const default {
   actions: {
      async method1({rootState, commit}){
         // if its the first call to deferred, the value should be loaded through the API
         // otherwise the stored value should be used
         const lazyLoadedValue = await rootState.sharedModule.deferred;
         // do something with lazyLoadedValue
      }
   }
}
```

I probably could solve it using something like `Thenable`'s but it doesn't seem to fit Vuex style of `state`, `actions` and `mutations`.

What would be the proper way for Vuex?

Comment: Something like `if (this.state.foo == null) await this.dispatch('fetchFoo')`. Is this what you ask about?

Comment: Yes, that's basically what I want, but optimally I want the check `if (this.state.foo == null)` to be done inside the store, and not by the consumer of the store, or ideally that you can't even access the uninitialized store value. I worry that this could lead to some weird bugs when you can access the state without initializing since this value should be used in many other places to come.

Comment: The line above can be done in method1. This results in nullable state, i.e it should be consistently be used as v-if="foo?.bar" or foo?.bar. If you want to avoid this then await method1 before mounting a comp where it's used, via router hook or suspense